# Unable to run SQL Query in Test environment

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a very 'weird' issue with running my application in our test environment.
On my local machine there is no issue at all, running a .Net Core web api application using angular 2 with a SQL Server 2014 Database.
In my test environment the website runs in IIS which I published from my local machine to the test environment, change the connection to the database on the test environment.
The error I get is simply `Could not execute query`, but when I run said query on the database using SQL Server Management Studio on the test environment it runs fine.
When I change the connectionstring on my local machine to the database on the test-environment the application runs fine.
So I'm guessing it's a setting in my application that works fine on my local environment but not on the test environment.
Any ideas on where I might look or try next?

Comment: are u sure that is the entire error message ? Have you checked that you can reach your test db from here ? Do you connect with windows-authentication or with user/pass and if the latter is it correct ? So many things can be going on here

Comment: I am logging in and connecting with a specific database-user. I can use those credentials to connect to the database in SQL Server Management Studio and run a query.

Comment: but when you connect thru SSMS you are on a different computer than where this problem occurs ?

Comment: I can connect and execute queries with those credentials from my local machine and from the test environment as well. I have SSMS installed on the test environment as well.

Comment: what is the stacktrace there? is there a `.InnerException`? this *sounds* like some tool / layer you are using is basically doing `catch { throw new InvalidaOperationException("useless message"); }` that is hiding the real error, in which case... I'd blame whatever tool you're using for hiding the actual problem :) However, you can always use your own `SqlConnection` instance to try to connect directly using the same connection string, create a command (`select getdate();` should work...) and execute it; that should tell you the actual problem. Firewall or connection string error possibly.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I got a different exception: 
`Unable to connect to SQL database '<databaseName>' for cache dependency polling. `